# App is crashing after publishing on playstore update but running ok from android studio (Duplicat But unable to find solution)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Greeting Experts. I am new to android. I tried every solution but all in vain. please don't tell me this is stupid question.
i published an app Named "Ertugral GHazi" when i install it from android studio to mobile directly it is working fine . but after major update app is crashing on every device.
I tried Try catch on every block of code but same thing is happening.
crash log is below.

App [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sourceinflow.ertugrulinurdu) of playstore

```
> --------- beginning of crash 2020-06-22 23:17:43.725 2091-2091/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.sourceinflow.ertugrulinurdu, PID: 2091
>     java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
>         at com.sourceinflow.ertugrulinurdu.MainActivity$d.a(:4)
>         at j.g$b$a$a.run(Unknown Source:37)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

My Gradle settings are below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sourceinflow.ertugrulinurdu"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
//    implementation 'com.dailymotion.dailymotion-sdk-android:sdk:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.6'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'

    //retrofit and gson
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
}
```

Project Level Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Tip: whenever you upload an apk on playstore, also append the obfuscation mapping-file too in order to decode the exception stack trace for future. The stack points towards `MainActivity$d.a(:4)` and `j.g$b$a$a.run(Unknown Source:37)` but now we don't know what's its actual class and call.

Comment: where to append append the obfuscation mapping-file...

Comment: App -> Android Vitals -> Deobfuscation files

Comment: This issue might be caused by incompatible data from your apps previous version.Try out the following: Checkout your old code and install the previous version of your app via Android Studio. Then checkout the newest version and install the new version.

Comment: Did You test the update to the new major release also in Android Studio? Run old version and update the code und run the version?

Comment: Thank you all guys. But i changed from true to false again in gradle (app level) for minifyEnabled false and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things can do this problem in my case I had the same issue.. and the problem was in Admob App ID

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).